# Hadoop 2.7.1 on Windows 7 64 bit: Failed to setup local dir

Tags: permissions, windows-7-x64, hadoop2

I am trying to configure Hadoop 2.7.1 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine following this article: 
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure

I have successfully created the hadoop build for windows using maven and configued the same. However, when i am trying to execute the following command for a sample map-reduce job, i am getting application failure error:

```
D:\hadoop>bin\yarn jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar wordcount /input output
```

> Error:
>   Application application_1441785420720_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1441785420720_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode:-1000
>
> Diagnostics:
>   Application application_1441785420720_0003 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1441785420720_0003_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000
>   For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://SGH419R1Z8:8088/cluster/app/application_1441785420720_0003 Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
>
> Diagnostics: Failed to setup local dir /tmp/hadoop-rabindra/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good. Failing this attempt. Failing the application.

Based on my research on this issue for the last 3 days, i am confident that this is a permissions issue but i am just not able to figure out the solution for the same. I'd really appreciate any help you can provide on this.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by configuring hadoop in a different partition than the system drive (C:) because it had different permissions requirement for Windows.

Comment: I already configured in (F:) drive. Still the problem exists. But if i start services when my lap is connected in domain in my office. This permission  problem wont occur. Job get succeeded.